# Задержка между событиями клавиатуры и мыши

Tags: javascript, события

Есть `<input type="text">`.
Проблема заключается в том, что после срабатывания событий клавиатуры (допустим клавиша Enter, либо другую символьную клавишу) и потом сразу же делаем клик (Touchpad) по input, то event loop не отлавливает события мыши. Начинает отлавливать после задержки ~800 ms.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('keyboard');
var prevTime = new Date().getTime();
el.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
   console.log('keyup');
   var curTime = new Date().getTime();
   console.log(curTime - prevTime);
   prevTime = curTime;
}, false);

el.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
   console.log('mousedown');
   var curTime = new Date().getTime();
   console.log(curTime - prevTime);
   prevTime = curTime;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keyboard">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересный моменты, задержка происходит только символьных клавиш и только на Touchpad.

ОС: Windows 10,
Chrome: 68.0.3440

Почему может event loop не отлавливает сразу событие?

Comment: В приведенном примере все события отлавливаются

Comment: @AntonShchyrov немного обновил вопрос. Суть в том что если нажать символьную клавижу, а потом очень быстро кликнуть мышкой, то событие не отлавливается (windows).

Comment: у меня все норм `keyup
1536849817028
mousedown
1536849817050`

Comment: @Дмытрык написал про мышь, а сам кликаю по тачпаду. Да вы правы с мышкой нормально все. С Тачем какая-то беда.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что проблема именно в js/браузере? Задержка в почти секунду должна быть очень легко заметна на глаз — в любых других программах проверяли? Может, это специальная защита тачпада от случайных кликов?

Comment: @andreymal в опере аналогично отрабатывает. По поводу защиты интересное мнение, но тогда бы, я думаю, задержка была бы не только на символьных клавишах.. хотя это не показатель, наверное

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick попробуйте не в браузере вообще. Откройте, например, WordPad и кликните, например, «Полужирный» после нажатия этой самой символьной клавиши

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы. В ворде так же отрабатывает

Comment: Ну значит дело точно не в js)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, я чего то верил, что это можно как то пофиксить с js-ом )

Comment: js просто покорно пробрасывает системные события клавиатуры и мыши, и вряд ли на них можно повлиять как-то, кроме как ковырянием настроек тачпада

Comment: Возможно дело в задержке реакции на касания, установленной по умолчанию. Правда она 300мс, а не 800. Вот как ее можно убрать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238587/eliminate-300ms-delay-on-click-events-in-mobile-safari

Comment: @andreymal действительно, причина оказалась в настройках touchpad'а. В windows 10 это пуск -> Mouse Setting -> Touchpad и нужно отрегулировать чувствительность (sensetivity).

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, зачем вы [предлагаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/326280) утвердить правку, в которой сносят сниппет?

Comment: Упс, не заметил, что js из снипета грохнули

Comment: Может точпад нужно настроить настройках панели управления?

Answer (score 0):

Вы же видите, что в примере в вопросе задержки не происходит. Мы должны догадаться, что Вы не показали? Пожалуйста:

> клавиша Enter

Задержка вызвана отправкой формы и перезагрузкой страницы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в текущем примере задерка происходит не только на клавише Enter. На любой символьной клавише.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Я на Windows 10, Chrome 68.0.3440.106.

Comment: Оказалось, только на тачпаде воспроизводится